# Is there an empirical rule for selecting the value of label smoothing?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, cross-entropy

I am wondering if there is any emperical rule for selecting the value of label smoothing when training a neural network. Let's define smoothed prediction targets in relation to a value $\epsilon$ to be:

$$y'_k = \begin{cases} 
1-\epsilon, y_k = 1\\
\epsilon / K, y_k = 0
\end{cases}$$
Where $K$ is the number of classes.

I am specifically wondering if $K$ should affect the value of $\epsilon$. My intuition tells me that a wider selection should translate to increased uncertainty and therefore larger $K$ should mean larger $\epsilon$. Is there any agreed upon best practice for selecting the value of $\epsilon$ or should it be adjusted experimentally?

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve by changing $\epsilon$? If your intention is to optimize the quality of some model with respect to some data, then naturally the result will depend on the model and the data. In this case, the "empirical rule" is "choose the value of $\epsilon$ which is optimal (discovered by experimentation)."

Comment: That is my goal. I am looking for a good starting value. For example, when adding dropout to an MLP, it is generally suggested to have a value of 0.8 for the first layer and 0.5 for all others. Is there any such rule for label smoothing?

Comment: Label smoothing strength is just a hyperparameter - in the end you are interested in some metric like accuracy, or F1, so you can tune label smoothing to optimize your metric value on evaluation set.